# binding an image source in XAML

Tags: silverlight, xaml, image

I am trying to bind an image source to my XAML through c#

this works

```
<Image Source="images/man.jpg"></Image>
```

this does not work

```
<Image Source="images/{Binding imagesource}"></Image>
```

where imagesource is a string variable in the c# file of this xaml and is being set equal to "man.jpg"

Answer (score 3):

You can't stick a binding mid-way through the value like that. It's either a binding, or it's not. Assuming imagesource is publicly accessible via your `DataContext`, you could do this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding imagesource}"/>
```

However, if it's been set to "man.jpg" then it won't find the image. Either set imagesource to the full path ("images/man.jpg") or use a converter:

```
<Image Source="{Binding imagesource, Converter={StaticResource RelativePathConverter}}"/>
```

The converter would prepend "images/" onto its value. However, it may be necessary for the converter to return an `ImageSource` rather than a `string`.

Comment: I changed imagesource to the full path "images/man.jpg" it is still not working. What do you mean it should be publicly accessible in the DataContext? I changed its access modifier to public and made get function for it as well, still doesnt work.

Comment: What is your DataContext? Have you set it? Look for binding errors in Visual Studio's output window.

Comment: Image.Source property is not a string, so this will not work.

Comment: @digitalSurgeon: hence, the last sentence in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

here is a way how to do it in XAML:

add this to the namespace:

```
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

then add your images paths

```
<System:String x:Key="ImageRefresh">/Theme;component/Images/icon_refresh.png</System:String>
<System:String x:Key="ImageSearch">/Theme;component/Images/icon_search.png</System:String>
```

This is how you use it

```
<Image Height="16" Source="{StaticResource ImageSearch}" Stretch="Uniform" Width="16"/>
```

This works ok, but if you load your xaml style in Blend it will go bogus..

An object of type "System.String" cannot be applied to a property that expects the type "System.Windows.Media.ImageSource".

I haven't figured out yet, how to replace System:String with that Media.ImageSource... but hey.. it works for me in Visual Studio.

Comment: ImageSource as a static resource works in Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Images have bitten me in the past. There is a certain lookup order involved.

When you use "image/man.jpg" it could refer to a file inside your silverlight xap, or relative to the location of XAP file. For example, it could be in YourProject.Web/ClientBin/image/man.jpg.

You should troubleshoot by using full URLs first and find out if this works.

Answer (score 0):

`imagesource` needs to be an actual `Image` object, not a `string`.

Here is a method that will create a new `Image` object given a path:

```
public BitmapImage Load(string path)
{
    var uri = new Uri(path);
    return new BitmapImage(uri);
}
```

Comment: this does not work for some reason. My app refuses to load it just gets stuck at 100%

Comment: Did you try the full path or the relative path? Should be full path. Also, I know my method works in WPF...perhaps it doesn't work in Silverlight for some reason.